# MySQL Table Comment Spanning Multiple Lines

Tags: mysql, sql

When creating a table in MySQL we can specify a comment.

Is anyone aware of a way to have the string passed to `COMMENT =` span multiple lines?

I've tried using a local variable that is the result of a CONCAT and also have tried using string literal syntax like `'foo ' 'bar ' 'baz'`

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT = 'some really long string that we want to span multiple lines instead of being limited to a single line';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To go along with @BillKarwin's answer: If you want to use multiple lines to create the comment, just do so:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    foo_id int primary key auto_increment,
    foo_name varchar(255)
)
COMMENT = 'this is a 
multi-line comment'
```

Unfortunately, you can't do any kind of concatenation in your comment construction (to split the actual DDL across multiple lines, while not having a line break in the actual DDL). For example, this is **not** possible:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(foo_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT) 
COMMENT = CONCAT('multi-line', 
    ' comment'
```

Of course, if you're accessing MySQL through a client language (PHP or Python or something), you can construct the string however you want:

```
ddl = (     "CREATE TABLE `foo` "
            "(`foo_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT) "
            "COMMENT='This is a multi-line "
            "coment")
```

Comment: This is somewhat better but I'd prefer not to have new line characters in the table comment

Comment: @BrushyAmoeba: It doesn't seem like you can have a multi-line comment (in your script) without having the new line in the definition. I updated my answer to indicate that you can that in some other client you use to talk to MySQL...

Comment: Ahhh thanks, thats a good idea. I could just write a python script as a layer over my SQL and all I really lose is the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` if you want to embed a newline.

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='some really long string\nthat we want to span multiple lines\ninstead of being limited to a single line'
```

The comment will still appear as one long string if you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to view it. That statement returns the exact syntax it would take to recreate the table, so if it requires using `\n` to put newlines in, that's what it will show.

But you can output the newlines as actual line breaks if you query the table metadata from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='foo'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: def
   TABLE_SCHEMA: test
     TABLE_NAME: foo
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: InnoDB
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Compact
     TABLE_ROWS: 0
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 0
    DATA_LENGTH: 16384
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 0
   INDEX_LENGTH: 0
      DATA_FREE: 0
 AUTO_INCREMENT: 1
    CREATE_TIME: 2018-10-02 23:37:57
    UPDATE_TIME: NULL
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8mb4_general_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS: 
  TABLE_COMMENT: some really long string
that we want to span multiple lines
instead of being limited to a single line
```

Comment: I don't want newlines in the comment though, I just want the string itself to be able to span multiple lines in my script. without having newlines in the actual comment

Comment: That sounds like an issue with line-wrapping in your text editor, not a problem with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Simple lines can be like:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    password="pwd",
    database="dbname"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
table_string_construct = """
    CREATE TABLE foo (
        company VARCHAR (255),
        col2 VARCHAR (255),
        col3 VARCHAR (255)
        )
    """
mycursor.execute(table_string_construct)
```